# how to print function value between double qoutes?

Tags: php

i was learning some basics in PHP so i was confused about two statements :

```
print("${phpinfo()}");
```

its print result of the function . so i tried to make it depends on user input , so i make this statement:

```
print("$_GET[z]");
```

but when i passed this value `${phpinfo()}` its print `${phpinfo()}` not like the first statement .
so how can i make this correct and print the result of the function not print its name .

Comment: welcome to SO, you can simply use `echo phpinfo();`

Comment: @DroidDev im not searching for how to print function . im looking for the way that i put in the first statement .

Comment: tell me what result you need using print?

Comment: i need to let user determine what function he want to print , so make this statement 
print("$_GET[z]"); and in the url he see this site.com/a.php?z=${phpinfo()} but this print the name for function . this is my question

Comment: using parentheses, braces and symbols in URL is not best practice. please encode that and send it.

Comment: why i need to encode ?

Comment: _i need to let user determine what function he want to print_. Do **not** let users execute arbitrary code on your server! You’re asking for trouble…

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print result of the function, for example:

```
function result(){
    return "res";
}
```

Use `print_r(result());` -> [print_r()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php). You'll get `res` at the output.

Your function **must** return something, it could be an object, an array, a string or numeric value, boolean also. In this case you'll see the output in `print_r()` for each type of data or in `echo()` for string/numeric values.

In your case use

```
print_r($_GET["z"]);
```

Use of quotes means print some string. `"z"` - means index of array in variable `$_GET`.
Also, read the [difference between using of single and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php).

Also, you can put an output value of the function into variable and then print it, but datatype of this output must be string/numeric.

```
function result(){
   // return 333;
    return "eeee";
}
$s = result();

print_r("$s");
// Output is: eeee (or 333)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/oDjEM)

In case of array variable you can use `print_r()` in the way you are:

```
$_GET["a"] = "word";

print_r("$_GET[a]");
// Output is: word
```

But `$_GET["a"]` should has also only string/numeric datatype.

Here you can read about many cases of [string parsing process](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

In case of [print()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) function you can use it as:

```
$_GET['x'] = 'sss';

print "this is {$_GET['x']} !";
```

Again, value should has string/numeric datatype.

If you wanna get result from function, which presented as a string value you can use next code:

```
$_GET['z'] = "phpinfo()";
foreach ($_GET as $item){
    if (gettype($item) === 'string'){
       if (strpos($item,'()')) {
            $s = str_replace('()','',$item);   
            print $s();                       // execution 
        } 
    }
}
```

Here you can send the name of desired function as a string like `"phpinfo()"`.

You cannot use `${phpinfo()}` in `$_GET` [because of that](https://3v4l.org/rn3l5). It reads content and thinks that it's a variable, but it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks alot for this info ! , but i need to print the result in the way that i put , print("${phpinfo()}) --> print("$_GET[x]") .

Comment: @test3332, `print "{$_GET['x']}";`

Comment: what i mean is that i need to let the user determine what function he want to print , so thats i used this print("$_GET[z]"); .php?z=${phpinfo()} but not get output just the name of the function

Comment: @test3332, `.php?z=${phpinfo()}` should be like `.php?z=phpinfo()`

Comment: @test3332, you cannot use `${phpinfo()}` in `$_GET` because of [that](https://3v4l.org/rn3l5). It reads content and thinks that it's a variable, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Link with .php?z=phpinfo

and then

```
$z = $_GET['z'];
print_r($z());
```

But remember, this is vulnerable for attacks - just a reminder ;)

edit: you can also use `call_user_func`

```
print_r(call_user_func($_GET['z']));
```

Comment: Thanks alot thats cool , but why i cant just do this : 
$z = $_GET[z];
print($z);
and in the url .php?z=${phpinfo()}
why i cant do this ?